# Is there a Stack Exchange site for Business Finance?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know that there is a site on SE for asking about [*personal* finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/), but is there one for asking about business finance? For example, a question about [the lifetime value of a customer](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/calculating-ltv.pdf)--is there a place for that question to go?

On the Personal Finance and Money [tour page](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour), it says that that site is meant for questions about,

> Personal investing and asset allocation
>
> The financial aspects of homebuying
>
> Best practices for saving for retirement, education, and other goals
>
> Strategies for creating and sticking to a budget
>
> Strategies for earning and saving more money

It also says that it is not for questions about

> Anything not directly related to Personal Finance and Money
>
> Questions that are primarily opinion-based
>
> Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

A question about the lifetime value of a customer is not about anything *personal*, although it is about money.

Are questions about money in general like my example above appropriate for Personal Finance & Money SE, and if not, is there a different but appropriate site for them?

---

Also, I'm not to sure about the tags, so any help--if necessary--would be greatly apprecaited!

Comment: I suspect this question is too basic for [quantitative finance](http://quant.stackexchange.com/). That's for academics and professionals only so the only other alternative is to [propose a site on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only two options I could think of are Quantitative Finance, and [Startups](https://startups.stackexchange.com/).

Since it seems off-topic at Quantitative Finance as per the comments, Startups looks like your best bet. From their [help center](https://startups.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Starting or running a small business including partnership and corporate structures, business plans, finance, legal or IP issues

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems like a marketing and growth question.

It would be closed as off-topic on PersonalFinance, even if you asked there. However, this question is perfectly on-topic in the [Startups SE](https://startups.stackexchange.com/).

In fact, there are already questions about the [LTV](https://startups.stackexchange.com/q/5969/5834) and other [metrics](https://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metrics).

Comment: Zizouz answered before you, so he gets the ✔️. However, you had the links and were correct so I'll +1... +1 :)

Comment: @Dopapp Ha ha it's not about the rep, it's about helping. Glad you found a solution :)   I'll try and reap some rep from your questions in the Startups SE :)